# How To Sync Data From Specific App(s) Across Multiple Devices

Tags: sync, networking, data-transfer, multiple-devices, app-data

*I know some are going to skip over reading this and just think this is regular Android syncing, I can assure you this isn't the same. I'm **not** talking about sytem, email, social media, or calender apps. Most normal user apps don't sync data between devices. I'm **not** developing anything, so this question is posted from the viewpoint of an end user.*

***What I am trying to figure out***

How to sync data from a specific app to all my devices on my home network, without manually entering the data?

(**For Reference** one of the apps I want to sync data from is ShowBox. There are others, but I would be able to duplicate the solution provided)

**Steps I have taken so far is to**

- *contact developer(s)*/no luck
- *write a script*/no luck
- *get an app*/no luck
- *researched*/no luck

The answer I'm looking for will be basically non-device specific, but for sticklers at least for Android 4.1 and up. If the answer includes an app or other method, please include details with step-by-step instructions. **EDIT** Please don't include steps or apps that involve user interaction everytime, because I could manually transfer the data myself just as easy. One last request, it must be done locally. Not online, but do on home network.

**EDITED PER REQUEST**
In the reference (example) app above, the data I wish to sync would be watched videos and favorites. User data. Like stated above there are other apps I would also use the same solution/steps on.
Also if there is a way to automate the syncing.

Answer (score 2):

Now you're a bit vague when you say data but if I know what you're talking about then I would consider an app called **OneNote** by Microsoft.

1. You need to have a Microsoft account. Go to [Outlook](https://www.outlook.com) and sign up for an email there. You don't have to use that email. It just links all the Microsoft apps together.
2. Once you have created the email, download OneNote, both on your computer and all your other devices. Sign in with the email that you have created.

   It will give you plenty of features in which you can sync all your information that you need across all of your devices. For example, I have it on my phone and when I take a picture it is uploaded to OneNote and I can automatically see it on my computer.

   It will also sync all sorts of information and data that you need such as important documents like word Excel and PowerPoint and even video.

There are also a few other apps that can do the same thing.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect what data. I need a way to do it locally on home network, not online.

Comment: Its not the answer I need, so its not accepted. But I can use this for something else I want to do so +1

Comment: What are those others apps you think can do this? Can this be done locally?

Comment: This answer really doesn't address syncing data, and won't help others looking for a solution.

Answer (score -1):

You're a bit vague. But I think you are talking about application back-end datas. This is possible. You may want to use an app like Helium and Dallas Thomas explains how to use it in this article: http://gs5.wonderhowto.com/how-to/back-up-your-android-apps-their-data-without-root-0158767/

In Helium you just select the app data you want, find the apps and choose cloud backup.

Comment: Please include steps in using the app, so others can follow along as well.